# Expected spy<method_name> to have been called once.It is called 0 times

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am a newbie to Jasmine.Iam writing a UT to check if a service is being called in ngAfterViewInit function.

Below is my test code

```
describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component: HomePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;
  let service:DataloadService;
  let srvSpy:any;
  let compoSpy:any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomePage ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot()]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));
   it('getData method should be called on Init',()=>{
      srvSpy=jasmine.createSpy('getData').and.callThrough();  
      expect(srvSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      component.ngAfterViewInit();
      expect(srvSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });

});
```

Every time i run the script the test fails giving me the error

Expected spy to have been called once.It is called 0 times

How am i supposed to fix this?

Update:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import {DataloadService} from '../services/dataload.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {
  value:any;
  constructor(private srv:DataloadService) {}
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.srv.getData().subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.value=res;
        console.log(this.value);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's see your `ngAfterViewInit` code. It seems like you're not spying correctly at first glance.

Comment: I've updated my code with ngAfterViewInit

Comment: first do fixture.detectChanges() then fixture.whenStable, inside that have your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

I am surprised Angular testbed is not complaining since you didn't inject DataloadService

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
.....
describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component: HomePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;
  let service:DataloadService;
  let mockDataLoadService = jasmine.createSpyObj('srv', ['getData']); // add this line to mock the dataLoadService with public method of getData
  let srvSpy:any;
  let compoSpy:any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomePage ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot()],
      // stub out the real implementation of DateLoadService with our mock
      providers: [{ provide: DataLoadService, useValue: mockDataLoadService }],
    }).compileComponents();

    // make getData return Observable of 'hello world', it is up to you what you would like to return
    mockDataService.getData.and.returnValue(of('hello world'));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));
   // change the title of the test
   it('value should be changed on ngAfterViewInit', ()=>{
      component.ngAfterViewInit();
      expect(component.value).toBe('hello world'); // assert that it went inside of the subscribe block and made component.value to 'hello world'

  });

});
```